# Remove all text between "second vertical bar" and "third vertical bar" in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have following code:

```
|{{FRA|Richard Gasquet|Richard Gasquet}}<br />
|{{DEU|Christopher Kas|Christopher Kas}} {{DEU|Philipp Kohlschreiber|Philipp Kohlschreiber}}
```

I should do something with Notepad++ (if possible) to change it to look like the following:

```
|{{FRA}} [[Richard Gasquet]]<br />
|{{DEU}} [[Christopher Kas]] {{DEU}} [[Philipp Kohlschreiber]]
```

I guess it's not possible to do this with one try, but maybe after 2 search and replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do a Replace in Notepad++ with search mode "Regular expression"
2. use `\{\{([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|[^}]+\}\}` as the regex
3. Use `{{$1}} [[$2]]` as replacement string
4. Perform a Replace all